# CakePHP Adding new model association to existing table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have table foos and bars with a lot of data currently in them (well over 10,000 rows). I have now added a new relationship in the model `Foo belongsTo Bar` and `Bar hasOne Foo`.

I would now need to add columns foo_id and bar_id to the tables but how can I populate the columns easily with the existing data? I can't simply grab the data in cakePHP as the data array is too large. Is there a way to do this using mySQL or from the cake console?

Comment: How do  you want to populate the entry? What is the current link between the 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach this with a SQL based migration, or if that won't work a cake shell command that paginates through the foos and bars adding data to your new columns.